# MySQL SELECT JOIN with empty row returns

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following MySQL tables:

[users]

```
| id | name    |
|----|---------|
| 1  | John    |
| 2  | Anna    |
| 3  | Peter   |
```

[times]

```
| user_ID | date       | time   |
|---------|------------|--------|
| 1       | 2020-03-20 | 07:00  |
| 1       | 2020-03-21 | 08:00  |
| 3       | 2020-03-22 | 09:00  |
```

my query look like:

```
SELECT name, date, time 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN times ON times.user_ID = users.id 
WHERE date = '2020-03-22';
```

what i get is:

```
| name    | date       | time   |
|---------|------------|--------|
| Peter   | 2020-03-22 | 09:00  |
```

what i want is:

```
| name    | date       | time   |
|---------|------------|--------|
| John    |            |        |
| Anna    |            |        |
| Peter   | 2020-03-22 | 09:00  |
```

is there a way to join non existent lines (not fields!) in the times table with the users table?

Comment: Consider storing date and time as a single entity

Comment: I would use UNION instead of an Inner Join

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN`. And then you need to put the restrictions on the second table into the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT name, date, time 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN times ON times.user_ID = users.id AND date = '2020-03-22';
```

Answer (score 1):

use `left join` and move `where` clause to `on`:

```
SELECT name, date, time 
FROM users 
left JOIN times ON times.user_ID = users.id and date = '2020-03-22';
```

Comment: thank you! that gave me the right idea of how this is working. i already supposed about using left and right joins but i did it wrong with the where clause. now i'm into it thanks! can i also replace null fields with some default values? (like '00:00:00')

Comment: @3x3cut0r Yes you can if the [ifnull](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp) function